# Resetting quizzes in the R package learnr

Tags: r, shiny, learnr

I am developing an interactive quiz using the learnr package and Shiny and have noticed that once I select a response to a question, the package corrects my answer but I'm unable to reset the question to the default, restarting the R session doesn't work. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

Rodney

Comment: I found a solution. There is a startover button to the left at the bottom of the menu in the rendered learnr interactive document, that does the trick. This answer may prevent some grief if others run into this problem.